# Why am I offered an upgrade from 14.04 to 15.10, instead of 16.04.1

Tags: upgrade

I have been waiting for 16.04.1.  On 22/07/16, I received the email from Adam Conrad, informing that the upgrade was now available.

I opened Software Updater, but it only offered me an upgrade to 15.10.

Why is this?

Garry

The upgrade was offered to me late on Friday 29/07/16 (Australian EST).

Thanks for the comments...

Answer (score 1):

Because 15.10 is not end of life yet. It is today but that will be at the end of the day, not in the middle.

The 14.04 to 16.04.1 is NOT active yet. It should be yes, but it is not.

Comment: As of 9:00 PM EST, my 14.04 computers report that the upgrade to 16.04 is now available.

Answer (score -1):

The reason that you were not offered an upgrade from 14 to 16 is because attempts to upgrade from 14 to 16 have been known to cause severe failures (requiring re-install).

If possible: Clonezilla backup before any upgrade. A fresh 16-install can save you a lot of headaches and time.

Comment: Did you read the question?

Comment: Your edits still don't answer the question at all. Read the question again.